# Undefined variable in Laravel 8 (running php 8)

Tags: php, laravel

I try to show variable from the controller to blade in laravel but the result is "Undefined Variable"

UserController.php

```
 public function user(){
    $people = ['Edwin','James','Rock','Peter','Maria'];
    return view('user', compact('people'));
}
```

Web.php

```
Route::get('/user', function (){
return view('user');
```

});

user.blade.php

```
 @if(count(array($people)))
   <ul>
   @foreach($people as $person)
       <li>{{$person}}</li>
   @endforeach
   </ul> @endif
```

I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: your route should be pointing to your controller method since that is where you are actually passing data to the view and this view requires that data

Comment: `Route::get('/user',[\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class,'user'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your web.php file

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'user']);
```

Answer (score 0):

In route

Route::get('/user', function (){
return view('user');

That means you are directly loading the view ,  It will not go to controller . Instead use

Route::get('/user', 'UserController@user');

This will go to user method in usercontroller class